# Making my website mobile friendly and resize the calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I tried to add this to the HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I tried to add this to the CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .calculator {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1X5q.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe at the `position:` side. Are you sure that you made the `position: absolute` and not `position:fixed`